# javascript recursive with parameters to decrement

Tags: javascript, recursion, parameter-passing

hello I'm new learning recursive but i don't know to solve with this problem,
cause this one using 2 parameters, I don't know how to return with 2 arguments.

this is the normal loop ,`not a recursive` yet cause i dunno how to change it to `recursive`:

```
function deret2(num,num2){
  var tampung = 1;
   for (var i= num; i >= 1 ; i-= num2){

    tampung = tampung * i ;
  }
  console.log(tampung);
}
deret2(12,5); //12* 7 * 2 = 168
```

Edit : the recursive I made :

```
function deret(num,num2) {
  //var tampung = 1;
  if (num <= 0) { // terminal case
    return 1;
  } else 
  { // block to execute
    return num * deret(num-num2,num2); 
  }
};
deret(12,5);
```

it won't work cause `number* deret(2 arguments here)` ?? that's why i don't know how to make this a recursive with 2 parameters, how could u save it and multiply it against 2 arguments ?

Comment: Return where? There's neither `return` statement nor this is a recursive function.

Comment: yeah i want to change it to recursive , this is normal loop

Comment: So you will need a function that returns `num * deret2(num-num2,num2)`. And don't forget your base case...

Comment: recursive calling the function all over again ?

Comment: Dell, What do you think you're doing with a for loop? Looping is recursion.

Comment: @Mike: A for loop and recursion are not the same thing.

Comment: So what's wrong with your recursive function? It doesn't need any of the `tampung` stuff, but it should work.

Comment: Honestly, I understand nothing here. What is your question? What is the problem with the code you already have? Why is the accepted answer literally the same code as the question?

Comment: @TamasHegedus OP edited the answer there was no recursion code at the beginning.

Comment: @Megajin I see thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a recursive function with check.

You need for a recursive function a check if the recursion should stop, or if the function should call again with same or changed paramters. Then you need a value to return in both cases.

Rule of thumb, for multiplications return as last value `1` and for addition `0`.

> ```
> num  num2  return
> ---  ----  ------------------
>  12     5  12 * deret2(7, 5)
>   7     5   7 * deret2(2, 5)
>   2     5   2 * deret2(-3, 5)
>  -3     5   1
> ```

```js
function deret2(num, num2) {
    return num >= 1 ? num * deret2(num - num2, num2) : 1;
}

console.log(deret2(12, 5)); //12* 7 * 2 = 168
```

With if syntax.

```js
function deret2(num, num2) {
    if (num >= 1) {
        return num * deret2(num - num2, num2);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

console.log(deret2(12, 5)); //12* 7 * 2 = 168
```

Bonus: The shortest version.

```js
function deret2(num, num2) {
    return +(num < 1) || num * deret2(num - num2, num2);
}

console.log(deret2(12, 5)); //12* 7 * 2 = 168
```

Comment: You you you.. Always come with the best solution! `:P`

Comment: Not sure if someone who asks what a recursion is could understand a short-circuit? Anyway nice and short answer!

Comment: damn so it works with 12* funct(7,2) ... how does it multiply ?  why 12 not multiply to the 2nd number too ( ,2)?

Comment: the second parameter stays with `5`.

Comment: I agree with @Megajin that while very concise, it's not exactly the most readable form for the OP. Perhaps edit in the longer form to better illustrate what's happening?

Comment: I see only multiply with the 1st parameter, I thought the 2nd will join and add to somewhere .    thanks sir

Comment: @DellWatson: Try stepping through the code with a pencil and paper and it should be clearer. You are multiplying `num` by the result of calling `deret2(num-num2, num2`.

Comment: @DellWatson: So `12 * deret(7,5)` == `12 * 7 * deret(2,5)` == `12 * 7 * 2 * deret(-3,5)` == `12*7*2*1`

Comment: @MattBurland yeah I do understand how it works, thanks for more explaination sir, I missthought about multiply the 2nd parameter, and also my code didn't work cause my base was  `if (num <= 0)`  ?

Comment: @DellWatson: `if (num <=0)` should make no difference to the function. `<1` is more correct, but it shouldn't actually make a difference to the result. Worse case you end up with something like `6*1*1` instead of `6*1`, for example. Which means you wasted a loop, but you still get the correct answer.

Comment: (Could be slightly shorter - my JS console logs `4` for `true * 4` :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן, but with to small values, you get `true` instead of `1`, that's why the implicit conversion to number.

Comment: @NinaScholz what I'm saying is that when I multiply `true` by a number in my console, `true` functions as the number 1, so your code works for me without the plus and parentheses around the Boolean expression.

Comment: @גלעדברקן. yes, :), but the function would return `true` instead of `1`, like for example `deret2(0, 5);`.

Comment: @NinaScholz oh, I see, missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function calls itself, and with an extra parameter, we don't need to keep track of a mutating variable. Looping and recursion are very closely related, to the point where the transformation is mechanical.

```
function deret2(num,num2,tampung){
  if (num >= 1) {
    deret2(num - num2, num2, tampung * num);
  } else {
    console.log(tampung);
  }
}
deret2(12,5,1); //12* 7 * 2 = 168
```

Note that we're passing in the initial value of `tampung` directly now, instead of encoding it into the recursion. If you don't want the caller to pass the base value of `tampung`, it's fairly common to make a helper function to encode that base case and then start the recursion.

Comment: There is no need for an extra parameter at all

Comment: There is if you want tail recursion... but you're right, could just keep descending and multiplying `num * deret2(...)`

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function should have itself declared inside the function AND a stop if condition:

```
function deret2(startNumber,step){
   if(startNumber>= 1){
     return startNumber * deret2(startNumber - step, step);
   }else{
     return 1;
   }
}
deret2(12,5); //12* 7 * 2 = 168
```